# Spring boot, Spring Security, React - The Custom Filter Authentication not working

Tags: spring-security

At the custom filter the username and password from the Request is showing null.
Through browser: http://username:password@localhost:8090/login
I am assuming this will invoke default login  the Spring Security.
At the custom filter the username and password from the Request is showing null even I give correct username and password. So credential fail. So 403 is returned.
Is the custom filter not getting registered or not getting the Request. Any help. Thanks in advance.

WebSecurityConfig.java file:

```
 //WebSecurityConfig.java file

package com.example.demo.configuration;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import com.example.demo.services.AuthenticationProviderService;
import com.example.demo.filters.DtscCustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private DtscCustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter dtscCustomerUsernamePasswordAutenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProviderService authenticationProvider;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
        http.addFilterAt(dtscCustomerUsernamePasswordAutenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);   
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    }
```

DtscCustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:

```
//DtscCustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java file

package com.example.demo.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

    @Component
    public class DtscCustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Value("${jwt.signing.key}")
    private String signingKey;

    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain   chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String username = null;
        String password = null;
        
        System.out.println(request);
            try{
                username = request.getParameter("username");
                password = request.getParameter("password");
                    System.out.println(username);
                    System.out.println(password);
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        
        
        Authentication authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
        
        SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        HashMap<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
                claims.put("username", username);
        
        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .signWith(key)
                .compact();
                response.setHeader("Authorization", jwt);    
        
                chain.doFilter(request, response);  
    }
    
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return !request.getServletPath().equals("/login"); }
    
    

}
```

AuthenticationProviderService:

```
//AuthenticationProviderService .java file
package com.example.demo.services;

import com.example.demo.respository.DtscUserDetails;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


    @Component
    @Service
    public class AuthenticationProviderService implements AuthenticationProvider{
    @Autowired
    private DtscUserDetailsService dtscUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            String username = authentication.getName();
            String password = String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());
            DtscUserDetails user = dtscUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            return checkPassword(user, password, bCryptPasswordEncoder);                
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
            return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    private Authentication checkPassword(DtscUserDetails user, String rawPassword, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
            if (encoder.matches(rawPassword, user.getPassword())) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                return auth;
            } else {
                        throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
                    }
    }

}
```

DtscUserDetailsService:

```
//DtscUserDetailsService.java file

package com.example.demo.services;

import com.example.demo.entities.DtscUser;
import com.example.demo.respository.DtscUserDetails;
import com.example.demo.respository.DtscUserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.function.Supplier;


@Service
public class DtscUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
     
    @Autowired
    private DtscUserRepository dtscUserRepository;
    
    @Override
        public DtscUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
          Supplier<UsernameNotFoundException> s = () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Bad Credentials!");

            DtscUser u = dtscUserRepository.findDtscUserByUsername(username).orElseThrow(s);

            return new DtscUserDetails(u);
        }

}
```

DtscUserDetails:

```
//DtscUserDetails.java file

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DtscUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final DtscUser dtscUser;

    public DtscUserDetails(DtscUser dtscUser) {
        this.dtscUser = dtscUser;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return dtscUser.getListOfDtscAuthority().stream()
                   .map(a -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(a.getUsername()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return dtscUser.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return dtscUser.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public final DtscUser getUser() {
        return dtscUser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `request.getParameter("username")` will extract username from querystring parameter instead of your given URL `http://username:password@localhost:8090/login`.

**Note:** Sending username and password in URL is security flow. Its not recommended. **Always use POST request with usename/password send in request body.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. It helped me.  If I use POST request I getting the username and password. But the response is {
    "timestamp": "2023-04-12T07:04:09.811+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/login"
}

Comment: Because after passing your filter its trying to find `/login` controller mapping. Which doesn't exists. Instead you should register custom authentication provider and use spring formAuthentication.

Comment: What you told is what happening. Now I removed the code line chan.doFilter(request, response); from the code of the custom filter. Is it Ok? Any side effects?. Please elaborate on the "register custom authentication provider "

Comment: The use case is the back end (Spring boot + Spring security + RDBMS)  need to receive the username and password in JSON from the SPA React Front end and authentication needed to be sent to the Front end.

Comment: You are using JWT authentication token?

Comment: Yes. The objective is to JWT Authentication. The additional filter for JWT is to be included.

Comment: Checkout how to do JWT with filter at https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-security-tutorial or with servlet filter https://springframework.guru/jwt-authentication-in-spring-microservices-jwt-token/